# issue with GITHUB API for technologies

Tags: python, api, github

i am attempting to use github api to get job postings for different technologies and then store them on a excel file, when i utilize this code i am not able to retrieve the information

```
import requests
baseurl = "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DA0321EN- 
SkillsNetwork/labs/module%201/datasets/githubposting.json"
response = requests.get(baseurl)
if response.ok:             
    data = response.json()
print(data)
number_of_jobs=data.groupby('technology').sum().loc[technology,:][0]
```

but when i try to execute i get an error saying 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'
any suggestion on how i can fetch the information and then store it on excel file?[image]

Comment: Do you want to use pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a csv file (which will be opened by Excel)

```
import requests
baseurl = "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DA0321EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/module%201/datasets/githubposting.json" 

response = requests.get(baseurl)
if response.ok:             
    data = response.json()
    with open('out.csv','w') as f:
      for e in data:
        f.write(f'{e["A"]},{e["B"]}\n')
```

out.csv

```
technology,number of job posting
java,92
C,184
C#,14
C++,24
Java,92
JavaScript,65
Python,51
Scala,47
Oracle,6
SQL Server,16
MySQL Server,5
PostgreSQL,17
MongoDB,4
```

Comment: once i create it,how do i access the Csv file?

Comment: This is a totally different question.  ( Open it with Excel ). Please accept the answer.